# Yammer embed feed not showing for some users

Tags: yammer

We are just setting up Sharepoint as part of office 365 for the first time.  I have enabled Yammer and embedded the feed using the default settings.  It shows up on my page as expected but another colleague cannot see anything or sees a Yammer box with no feed.

Does anyone have a solution?  Or a way to troubleshoot this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: is that colleague logged into Yammer?

Comment: I would check the permissions that the user has. I've noticed that if a user is logged into yammer but does not have permission to the channel you have in the embedded feed it will display nothing at all. 

One other thing is to check which browser they are using. Chrome and Safari respect the X-Frame-Options header that is sent over while Firefox and IE (v11) ignore it (so they work just fine).

Comment: Hi, thanks for responses.  Yes, colleagues were logged into Yammer.  Mixture of browsers in use - I tested the main ones.  Oddly, after several weeks, the Yammer embed started working - not sure what was wrong or why it started working - maybe a bug was fixed?  In any case, it works as expected now.